# Need a batch script to copy certain folder and subfolders into other folders in different directory

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have to make a script to copy a folder and it's subfolders from one directory into another directory which has hundreds of folders with different name.

The folder structure is similar to below:

Source (Directory M:)

```
Folder1
--------Subfolder1
--------Subfolder2
--------Subfolder3
```

Destination (Directory O:)

```
Folder A
--------SubfolderA

Folder B
--------SubfolderA

Folder C
--------SubfolderA

...

Folder xxx
--------SubfolderA
```

So far I made it up to this stage but can't get it working.

> First I run this piece of code to get the list of folders in the
>   destination directory and export it to a text file

```
dir /b /ad > c:\temp\folder-list.txt
```

Now I need to tell the script to copy the folder/subfolders from source to destination but I can't get it working.

```
 FOR  %%i in (c:\temp\folder-list.txt) DO xcopy /t /e M:\Folder1 %%i\SubfolderA\
```

Please help.

PS: Script should copy a folder to other folders which have random names.

I think, I'm making some progress here:

```
for /d %%a in ("O:\*") do if exist "%%a" xcopy /t /e "M:\Folder1" %%a\SubfolderA
```

but I'm getting the error below.

> Invalid number of parameters

Comment: What happens? Does it not copy?

Comment: The issue is, I don't know how to point the xcopy to the destination folders. I mean the O:\destination folders\SubfolderA

Comment: What is the expected result? Where should Folder1 and Subfolder1 end up?

Comment: Since the destination directory includes hundreds of folders with different names. The folder1 and all of it's subfolders should be  copied into all the SubfolderA's in destination directory.

Comment: Neíther from your descriptipn/code nor from the layout it's clear what you want to copy where. And it does look like a question for [SU] not [SO]

Comment: Tell me which part you couldn't understand so I can explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
for /d %%a in ("O:\*") do if exist "%%a" xcopy /t /e "M:\Folder1\*" "%%a\SubfolderA"
```